# Резервное копирование БД в Google Drive

Tags: android, sqlite

Есть приложение, которое работает с БД. БД изначально лежит в папке `assets` и пользователь добавляет в нее записи. Хотелось бы сделать резервное копирование БД в Google drive и возможность импортировать БД из google drive. Какие есть варианты для этого?

Answer (score 1):

Вариант один, использовать [Google Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java).
Сначала [создаем](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder) на GDrive папку для приложения (изначально стоит [проверить](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files) есть ли она там), потом берем нашу БД из ассетов и [загружаем](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads) в папку приложения.
Для импорта [загружаем](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads) БД из GDrive на устройство и перезаписываем.

Comment: А есть какие-нибудь ресурсы, где описан данный процесс? Я реализовала авторизацию в приложении через Firebase, далее пыталась по документации что-то сделать, но непонятно например что такое driveService, откуда берется folderId и другие вещи.